# Circular Images - Apply Tint on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to apply a tint of `#e30009` on hover of some images.

I tried with Javascript and a `div` that was placed over the image, however the overlay kept flashing on mouseover?.

See my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vX96M/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    overlay = $("#overlay");
    img = $('#rob');
    overlay.width(img.css("width"));
    overlay.height(img.css("height"));
    overlay.css("top", img.offset().top + "px");
    overlay.css("left", img.offset().left + "px");
    overlay.css('opacity',0);
    $('#rob').delay(500).hover(function() {
        $('#overlay').fadeTo('slow',0.9);
    })
})
```

I also tried with pure CSS but I cannot seem to achieve the correct color. I did:

```
img:hover { -webkit-filter: sepia(90%) hue-rotate(90deg); }
```

Comment: Perhaps a JSFiddle example...have you tried other setting that `hue-rotate(90deg)`...perhaps another angle?

Comment: Added JSfiddle example displaying flicker in JS with tint

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but the jsfiddle seems to work just fine for me in both safari and firefox... what exactly is it doing that it shouldn't be?

Comment: sorry posted the wrong jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Best bet here is to probably set the overlay as "display:none;", delegate the events and then use an addClass vs removeClass function. Main issue is that the overlay is interfering with the mouseover events, so just add another function for that. See jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/vX96M/2/

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', "#myimg", function () {
   $('#overlay').addClass("show-as-block");
}).on('mouseleave', "#myimg", function () {
   $('#overlay').removeClass("show-as-block");
});

$(document).on('mouseenter', "#overlay", function () {
   $('#overlay').addClass("show-as-block");
}).on('mouseleave', "#overlay", function () {
   $('#overlay').removeClass("show-as-block");
});
```

Also should set the width and height of the overlay and then have a class to display as block.

```
.overlay {
display: none;
position: absolute;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: rgba(200, 100, 100, 0.5);
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
width:280px;
height:280px;
z-index:0;
}
.show-as-block {
 display:block;
}
```